# lateerror when retrieving an object from firebase in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a view which uses the getproductbyid function in order to get the product object from the database, when I get it in the view like this:

```
class _ProductDetailsViewState extends State<ProductDetailsView> {
  late Future<Product?> _productFuture;
  bool _isOnline = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkConnectivity();
  }

  void _checkConnectivity() async {
    _isOnline = await _isConnected();
    _productFuture = _isOnline ? getProductById(widget.barcodeValue) : Future.value(null);
    setState(() {}); // Trigger a rebuild after checking connectivity
  }

  void _showFullScreenImage(String imageUrl) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => FullScreenImage(imageUrl: imageUrl),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> _isConnected() async {
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
      return result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty;
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      return false;
    }
  }


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder<Product?>(
    future: _productFuture,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!_isOnline) {
        return Center(
          child: Text(
            'No internet connection. Please check your network settings.',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 18.0,
            ),
          ),
        );
      } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      } else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data == null) {
        return Center(
          child: Text(
            'Product not found',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 18.0,
            ),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        Product product = snapshot.data!;
        List<FoodAdditive> additives = product.checkForAdditives();
        int additiveScore = product.countCombinedRatings(additives);
          return Scaffold(
```

I don't get any errors in the UI but I check the console and I see: The following LateError was thrown building ProductDetailsView(dirty, state:
_ProductDetailsViewState#fb0ad):
LateInitializationError: Field '_productFuture@51144076' has not been initialized.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
ProductDetailsView
ProductDetailsView:file:///C:/Desktop/project/lib/pages/scan_screen.dart:86:11

here is the code in scan_screen.dart:86:11:

```
          showModalBottomSheet(
  context: _scaffoldKey.currentContext!,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  builder: (context) => DraggableScrollableSheet(
    expand: false,
    initialChildSize: 0.3,
    maxChildSize: 0.85,
    builder: (context, scrollController) => ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0), // Set your desired border radius
  child: Scaffold(
    line 86 -> body: ProductDetailsView(
      barcodeValue: barcode.rawValue ?? '',
      scrollController: scrollController,
    ),
  ),
),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you call `_checkConnectivity()` (which is an `async` function) from `initState`. But `initState` can't be async so you can't use `await _checkConnectivity()`.

As a result the `build` method of `ProductDetailsViewState` will be called **earlier** than the `await _isConnected()` is completed. Therefore the value of `_productFuture` will not be set at the time when `build` is invoked. This is what the error tells. Calling `setState(() {});` will not help because it will be invoked **after the first build** which already triggered the error at that time.

In your case you have two futures depending on each other: first you need `await _isConnected()` to be completed, then set `_productFuture` depending on the result, which you finally will use in a `FutureBuilder`.

In order to solve this you need two `FutureBuilder` widgets: one 'outer' to get the value of `_isOnline` and within this another 'inner' `FutureBuilder` that will be set the value of `_productFuture` depending on `_isOnline`.

Comment: _isOnline shouldn't be set by a futureBuilder no? it's just a variable to check if the user is online. can you help me with a code snippet?

Comment: `_isOnline = await _isConnected();` So this is a future. If any build depends on it it has to be a `FutureBuilder`. The code is very similar to what you have done so far, just a `FutureBuilder<bool>`, and inside it a `FutureBuilder<Product?>`.

Comment: If those two futures would be independent you could use `Future.wait` but since they are dependant you have to have to embed the second into the first.